# Issue in managing activity stack

Tags: android, back-stack

My app contains four activities viz Checkout, Login, Otp, Payment. The flow of these activities is like :
**Case 1.** If a user want to do payment and is already logged in, then user will be directly directed from checkout to payment screen.

**CheckoutActivity** -> **PaymentActivity**

and here on PaymentActivity if user press the back button he must be directed to CheckouActivity.

**Case 2.** If user is not logged in then he will be directed from CheckoutActivity to LoginActivity. Here the flow will be:
**CheckoutActivity** -> **LoginActivity** -> **OtpActivity** -> **PaymentActivit**.

and here in this case if he press back button on PaymentActivity he must be directed to LoginActivity.

How can we handle this flow of activities ? Please help.

Comment: StartActivity using startActivityForResult() and handle callback inside onActivityResult().

Comment: in case 2. He must be redirected to LoginActivity or CheckoutActivity??

Comment: @maheryhaja user must be directed to LoginActivity

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain the login flag in share preference.Then you need to write logic in PaymentActivity-> onBackPressed method according to your flag.

`@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    }`